# Как можно усыплять и будить потоки в си pthread

Tags: c, многопоточность, unix, распараллеливание, pthread

Я хочу сделать так, чтоб поток, доходя до определенного места засыпал, и когда все остальные потоки доходили до этого же места, все потоки просыпались и продолжали выполнение. Как это можно реализовать на си используя pthread?

Comment: выглядит как классический пример использования семафоров.

Comment: если все остальные потоки тоже должны ждать, в этот момент, то это банальный барьер... если продолжать работу, то я б на условной переменной делал (если средствами pthread ограничиваться)...

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` .. `pthread_cond_broadcast`